# How to export a plotly graph in R which would be possible to open in each computer?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to ask you if you could help me with exporting a plotly graph in R. Once the graph is generated (p), I want to save it as .html file. I do it by using:

`htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), file = "x.html")`

Unfortunately, when I send it to my collegue, he is not able to open it. He just gets white browser with:

> "--- title: plotly header-include: |- head: '' background-color: white
>   --- "

Any idea how to make the graph openable from the another computer?

Comment: I would create a. Rmd file with only one chunk: the plot, and render it as html. The resulting file can be opened from any browser

Comment: @PavoDive sorry for the late response. I did what you had proposed, thank you very much